# opening a URL from servlet

Tags: java, html, jsp, servlets, model-view-controller

I have created a webapp using MVC. I show several links to user on a page. These links will be links to some external sites. When user clicks on these links I want to record some data in my database and then redirect the user to the clicked link in a new tab. After I have recorded details in the database I also want to show updated page to the user.
I have a controller Servlet which directs to a action class which will record the details of the link that is clicked. Now I have to show two views to the user own the updated page of webapp and also the external link. I am able to do only one of them. Is it possible to provide both view to user?

In this way I am printing the URL :

```
<a href=
    <%  out.println(favBean.get(i).getURLLink());   %> >
    <% out.println(favBean.get(i).getURLLink());%>
</a>
```

Comment: Do you want to show merged views (local and external) on same page?

Comment: then put those view in one Jsp then when the link was clicked then after the process return it to the same jsp with the updates

Comment: how do you return the updates to your page? please include your servlet. :)

Comment: I dont want to merge Views. A external page should be opened according to the link. One page will be the page of my web app which will show the updated view.

Comment: @Secondo I return the updates in request parameter.
RequestDispatcher d = request.getRequestDispatcher("WEB-INF/"
     + nextPage);
   d.forward(request, response);

Comment: hmm now i understand you cannot use redirect() and forward at the same time in a servlet .. let me think about it :)

Comment: i think you need something like javascript in your page.

Answer (score 1):

You could use [Jquery Ajax](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/) to do this:

```
<a class="link" href=
  <%  out.println(favBean.get(i).getURLLink());   %> >
  <% out.println(favBean.get(i).getURLLink());%>
</a> 


<script>
    $(".link").click(function(){
       //first do the servlet DB stuff
       jQuery.ajax({
         type:"POST",
         url : "myServlet",
         data : param,
         success : function(data) {
         //on servlet DB stuff success open link in new tab
          var address = $(this).attr("href");
          windows.open=address;
        });
    });
</script>
```

Servlet only workaround with little bit of Plain JavaScript:

```
<% if( request.getAttribute("href") != null){ %>
 <script>
    document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function(){
       windows.open='<%=request.getAttribute("href")%>'
     });
 </script>
<%}%>

<a href='/callMyDBGetServlet?redirect=<%=favBean.get(i).getURLLink()%>' >
  <% out.println(favBean.get(i).getURLLink());%>
</a> 


doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response){

    String href = request.getParameter("redirect");
    //Do my DB stuff
    request.setAttribute("href");
    request.getDipatcher("sameJsp.jsp").forward(request,response);
 }
```

Comment: Is it not possible to do it with servlets and JSPs?

Comment: It is possible but it would be a nasty workaround. Jquery solution is much better IMO. I'll update the servlet example.

Comment: well I just realized even then you would need a tiny bit of Plain Javascript (Not Jquery).. :/